# Can I use my existing Intellij License for Java and javascript development in Macbook Air?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am planning to buy a [13 inches Macbook Air](http://www.apple.com/in/macbookair/specs.html) in India . I have recently purchased a Intellij License for about 50 dollars which indeed was a nice deal . Can I use this license to do development in Macbook Air or is that license only usable for Windows environment ? I mainly do Java/Javascript development. Is there any specific gotchas that I should know before making this expensive purchase ? If there are any gotchas are those solved with Mabook Pro ?

P.S: I am absolutely new to Mac World with prior experience in Windows only .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to use your personal license on **any number of computers**
(and **under different systems**). However, IDE checks for the number of
running copies on the local network when starting. In case it finds
any copies started with the same license, they are all shut down
except the last one.

In other words, you can use it anywhere, just **not concurrently**.

---

If you are a Windows user, it may take some time to get used to [Mac specific shortcuts](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/). Note that IDEA keymaps on Mac and on Windows are different and it may be hard to switch from one to another.

Performance of the recent Macbook Air should be enough for medium sized projects.

Comment: Are there any known issues with retina display for Intellij ? Please see my another question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75803/retina-dsiplay-support-on-intellj-idea-for-java-javascript-development)

Comment: There were some performance related issues on Retina, but most of them are either already fixed, or the fix is coming in the nearest updates (like slow editor when using block cursor).

Answer (score 2):

From [Intellij FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/licensing_faq.html#q1) you can read that:

- Can I run IntelliJ IDEA on different operating systems with the same
     license?

**You can run IntelliJ IDEA on different operating systems with the same license**, providing that it's not concurrently used.

- Can I use IntelliJ IDEA with the same license at work and at home?

A licensed user can run IntelliJ IDEA on different computers, regardless of location, provided that IntelliJ IDEA is not run concurrently on more than one computer. For example, you can run IntelliJ IDEA on your workstation at the office, OR on your laptop at home. But if you bring your laptop to the office, you may NOT run IntelliJ IDEA on both your laptop AND your workstation at the same time.

- What does your "per concurrent user" licensing mean?

A single license permits the use of IntelliJ IDEA by a single user at a time. For multiple concurrent sessions you must purchase multiple licenses.